# Get coordinates from Folium's feature LatLngPopup in Python

Tags: python, folium

I am looking for a way to get coordinates from a marker/popup in Folium.
I want to use the coordinates for further calculations.
I know, that Folium is more for visualizing data and maps than getting information back.

I found an interesting post where the coordinates were sent back via href (https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/353035/168662), but this does not work for me. I am displaying a folium map in a PyQt5 Window.

Here is a simple code to display the coordinates when clicking on a map with Jupyter Notebook:

```
import folium


m = folium.Map()
popup1 = folium.LatLngPopup()

m.add_child(popup1)
m
```

To get the coordinates, I want something like:

```
print("Latitude of Popup: ", popup1.getLat() )
```

Comment: I'm really interested in this as well, if someone has an answer...

Comment: Could you find an answer for this that works?

Answer (score 3):

Look at this site. I think this may interest you: https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/blob/master/examples/plugin-MousePosition.ipynb

```py
import folium
from folium.plugins import MousePosition


m = folium.Map()

MousePosition().add_to(m)

m
```

```py
m = folium.Map()

formatter = "function(num) {return L.Util.formatNum(num, 3) + ' º ';};"

MousePosition(
    position="topright",
    separator=" | ",
    empty_string="NaN",
    lng_first=True,
    num_digits=20,
    prefix="Coordinates:",
    lat_formatter=formatter,
    lng_formatter=formatter,
).add_to(m)

m
```

Comment: It only prints the coordinate on the map. The question however is how to export it outside of the map as a variable?

Comment: The code snippet was helpful