# Saving map in folder for further use

Tags: python, pyqt5, offline, folium, directory

I want to use my map for further offline calculations. I used the below code referred from ' [https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/313382/click-event-on-maps-with-folium-and-information-retrieval/377726#377726'](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/313382/click-event-on-maps-with-folium-and-information-retrieval/377726#377726%27) by user @Vlad Chuenko.
When I'm running the below code I'm not getting any error and desired output. How can I use it as offline!

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets
from folium.plugins import Draw
import folium, io, sys, json
import os

dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)
dir = r"data\map_update.html"
save_location = os.path.join(dirname, dir)

def saveMap():

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

        m = folium.Map(location=[19.5937,79.9629], zoom_start=5)
        folium.LatLngPopup().add_to(m)

        draw = Draw(
            draw_options={
                'rectangle': True,
                'marker': True,
                          },
            edit_options={'edit': False})
        m.add_child(draw)

        data = io.BytesIO()
        m.save(data, close_file=False)



        class WebEnginePage(QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage):
            def javaScriptConsoleMessage(self, level, msg, line, sourceID):
                coords_dict = json.loads(msg)
                coords = coords_dict['geometry']['coordinates'][0]
                print(coords)

    view = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
    page = WebEnginePage(view)
    view.setPage(page)
    view.setHtml(data.getvalue().decode())
    view.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
    m.save(save_location)
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I tried that, but no change not getting any output, folder is still empty. Is there any other way to do it!!

Comment: Your code will not do anything. Everything after `save_location = os.path.join(dirname, dir)` is inside the `def saveMap():` function which you never call. You have `if __name__ == '__main__':` *inside* a function which doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'm new to PyQt5. Is there is any way to save this map for offline calculations?

Comment: Have a go at fixing your code based on the observations I made previously - make sure you call `saveMap()` and move the `if __name__ == '__main__':` out of the function.